# Count the records of column relation on table with many to many

Tags: mysql, database, count, many-to-many, relational-database

I have 4 tables: `CLIENT_SERVICE`, `BOOKING`, `BOOKING_PETS`, `PETS`, basically one `clientService` could have many bookings and one booking could have many pets through `BOOKING_PETS` table. So I want to know the way to query for `CLIENT_SERVICE` records and count the total number of pets for each booking record.

For example, if I have 2 booking records, one with 2 associated pets, and another one with 1 associated pet, then I expect on response a column with the sum of the pets, something like this:

```
-----------------------------------
serv_id | bookingCount | petCount |
-----------------------------------
   1    |      2       |    3     |
-----------------------------------
   2    |      1       |    2     |
-----------------------------------
```

This is my actual query:

```
SELECT
    booking_id,
    cliserv_id AS id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT boopet_id) AS petCount
FROM CLIENT_SERVICE
LEFT OUTER JOIN BOOKING ON cliserv_id = booking_client_service_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    BOOKING_PETS INNER JOIN PET ON pet_id = boopet_pet_id
) ON booking_id = boopet_booking_id
GROUP BY cliserv_id, booking_id, boopet_id;
```

Comment: Just add one more `COUNT(..)` expression in your SELECT clause. In this case, to count all the pets in a client service, add `COUNT(Pets.pet_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need

```
GROUP BY cliserv_id, booking_id
```

If you include `boopet_id`, every group would end with only 1 pet.

Comment: The answer is so similar. I excluded `booking_id` from query and from group too and works as expected. I will mark as accepted because is the same theory but just applied for other fields